# Initializing the embedding tensor with a local numpy array

Tags: tensorflow

I want to initialize the word embedding layer from a local numpy array with the same shape, which is a pre trained embedding from another model.
It is OK if I did not add the partitioner param.
def word_embedding(shape, dtype=tf.float32, name='word_embedding'):

```
  f = open('./cnn_embed_array', 'r')
  embedding_array = pickle.load(f)
  f.close()
  print 'embedding_array loaded......'
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.variable_scope(name):
    return tf.get_variable('embedding', shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(embedding_array), trainable = False)
```

But if I add `partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(20)` in the tf.get_variable function, it give me error saying that the param is redundant.

`partitioner`  param tends to accelerate the training speed. Can I add the param in some other way ?

Answer (score 1):

If `trainable = False`, then the variable will not be learned and so partitioning won't help you. On the other hand, if you want this variable to be updated then you'll need to set `trainable = True`.